# Starting Sidekiq with rails server in development environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, background-process, sidekiq

I am using [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) for some of my background processes.

**Currently what I do is:**

start `bundle exec rails s`  on one terminal and then start `bundle exec sidekiq` on a different terminal so that the sidekiq starts itself and look for jobs to process.

**What I want is:**

As soon as i start `bundle exec rails s` it should also start the sidekiq `bundle exec sidekiq`.  How can i integrate it in just ***Development*** environment ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For apps like yours which require a number of services to be running consider using [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) and a `Procfile` to define those processes. Then you can use `foreman start` to run all of them in a single terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it like this:

```
bundle exec sidekiq & rails s
```